# Linking tables on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got myself in a bit of a mess on something I'm doing where I'm trying to get two tables linked together based on multiple bits of info.

I want to link one table to another based on the basic rules of(in this hierarchy)

- where main linking is where orderid matches between the two tables
- records from table 2 where valid=Y,
- from those i want the valid records which has the highest seqn1 number and then from those the one that has the highest seqn2 value

**table1**

```
orderid | date       | otherinfo   
223344  | 22/10/2020 | okokkokokooeodijjf
```

**table2**

```
orderid | seqn1 | seqn2 | valid | additonaldata 

223344  | 1     | 3     | y     | sdfsfsf        
223344  | 2     | 1     | y     | sffferfr       
223344  | 2     | 2     | y     | sfrfrefr  -- This row   
223344  | 2     | 3     | n     | rfrg66rr       
223344  | 2     | 4     | n     | adwere         
223344  | 3     | 4     | n     | adwere
```

so would want the final record to be

```
orderid | date       | otherinfo          | seqn1 | seqn2 | valid | additonaldata 
223344  | 22/10/2020 | okokkokokooeodijjf | 2     | 2     | y     | sfrfrefr
```

I started off with the code below but I'm not sure I'm doing it right and I can't seem to get it to pay attention to the valid flag when i try to add it in.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
left JOIN table2
ON table1.orderid = table2.orderid
AND table2.seqn1 = (SELECT MAX(table2.seqn1) FROM table2 WHERE table1.orderid = table2.orderid)
AND table2.seqn2 = (SELECT MAX(table2.seqn2) FROM table2 WHERE table1.orderid = table2.orderid 
AND table2.seqn1 = (SELECT MAX(table2.seqn1) FROM table2 WHERE table1.orderid = table2.orderid))
```

Could someone help me amend the code please.

Comment: Tag the actual database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) analytic function with partition by orderid and order by `SEQNR`s in the order you need. No need for multiple subselects. To add more selections for the single row, use `CASE` to map your values to numbers and order by them also.

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef542feef497bab19fde240e5beabe4f).

```
with l as (
  select *,
    rank() over(partition by orderid order by seqn1 desc, seqn2 desc) as rn
  from line
  where valid = 'y'
)
select *
from header as h
  join l
    on h.orderid = l.orderid
      and l.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
;
with cte_table2 as 
(
SELECT  ordered
       ,MAX(seqn1) as seqn1
       ,MAX(seqn2) as seqn2
FROM   table2
where  valid = 'y'
group by ordered --check if you need to add 'valid' to the group by but I don't think so.
)
SELECT
       t1.*
       ,t3.otherinfo          
       --,t3.[OtherFields]
from table1 t1
inner join cte_table2 t2 on t1.orderid = t2.orderid -- first match on id
left join table2 t3 on t3.orderid = t2.orderid and t3.seqn1 = t2.seqn1 and t3.seqn2 = t2.seqn2
```